# A puzzle about Green's function and S-matrix

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory

From the discussion in some posts [example1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/358415/why-is-the-s-matrix-element-essentially-the-residue-of-the-green-function-lsz-f), [example2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161443/why-are-green-functions-correlation-functions-not-on-the-mass-shell), we know that the S-matrix is the residue of the corresponding Green's function. On the other hand, S-matix is a physical observable in QFT, but Green's function is not gauge invariant in a gauge theory. How to fix this inconsistency?

Comment: Why do you say the S matrix is a physical observable? In experiments we measure cross sections, decay rates, momenta, energies, etc., but the S matrix is not something one measures directly, right?  It is not even a hermitian operator.

Comment: This is what I often heard.  See for example the discussion here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4331/is-the-s-matrix-the-only-quantum-field-observable